# Date Where Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need some help writing a where clause for a date field.

In my dataset, i have a date from and date to column which shows the absence from date and to date.

I need a where clause where if i search for a particular month, the results would show if the absence falls outwith the date parameter.

e.g absent from 01/08/2021 until 11/11/2021, and i run the report from 01/10/2021 - 31/10/2021, the results should show the persons record as they were absent for the month of Oct

TIA

Comment: could you please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the ranges are inclusive and you want to enclude the entirety of the day in the range then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   absences
WHERE  date_from <  DATE '2021-10-31' + INTERVAL '1' DAY
AND    date_to   >= DATE '2021-10-01'
```

*Note: If you are only storing dates at midnight then you can use `date_from <= DATE '2021-10-31'` but if you are storing dates with a non-midnight time component and want to include the entirety of the final day then you need to use `<` and add a day.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE absences (date_from, date_to) AS
SELECT DATE '2021-08-01', DATE '2021-11-11' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DATE_FROM | DATE_TO |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-08-01 00:00:00 | 2021-11-11 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e04094a1fde0ce6acec8fad6026962f2)*

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work